# Father process was block while set SIGCHLD

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, fork

This is my code, I had simplified it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void signal_handle(int sig)
{
    int status;
    wait(&status);
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0)
        signal(SIGCHLD, signal_handle);
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (execl("/bin/ls", "/", (char *)0) < 0)
        {
            perror("execl");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I found that, son process print the run result, but father process
was blocked.

what should I do, if a father has much son process? set `wait(&status)` for every one?

I'm very sorry for my bad english!

Comment: You don't need to test the status of `execl()` or any other member of the `exec*()` functions.  If it returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it does not return.

Comment: You should look more at the manual page for [`execl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl), the call should be `execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "/", NULL);`.

Comment: It's (sort of) OK as written; it tells the `ls` program that its name is `/` and `ls` lists the current directory since it has no file name arguments.  (But you're correct; that probably isn't what was intended.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the parent process would hang, and it doesn't on my machine.

After the `fork()`, the parent process invokes `signal()` to set the signal handler and immediately exits.  The child, meanwhile, executes `ls` to print the contents of the current directory (because the `"/"` argument becomes `argv[0]`, the program name, and there are no additional arguments).  It then exits too.  Except under very unlikely circumstances, the parent has exited long before the child completes.

If you want the parent process to wait until it gets the 'death of a child' signal, add a call to `pause()` in the parent-only execution path:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static void signal_handle(int sig)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid = wait(&status);
    printf("%d: signal %d child %d status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), sig, (int)pid, status);
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0)
    {
        signal(SIGCHLD, signal_handle);
        pause();
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "/", (char *)0);
        perror("execl");
        return -1;
    }
    else
        perror("fork");
    return 0;
}
```